# Spring java.sql.sqlexception: database is locked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Вообщем пишу веб-приложение на Java. Во время работы периодически создаются воркеры для сбора данных с использованием *spring-integration*. Это воркеры пишут некоторую информацию в БД. Иногда вознакает ошибка: `java.sql.sqlexception: database is locked`. БД `sqlite`.

Конфиг `hibernate`:

```
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->
    <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:/home/ivan/Dropbox/RssViewer/test.db" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rssviewer.domain" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Вот класс, отвечающий за обращение к БД:

```
@Repository
public class RssFeedDAOImpl implements RssFeedDAO {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public List<RssFeed> getAll(RssStream rssStream) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query;
    if (rssStream != null) {
      query = session.createQuery("FROM RssFeed WHERE rssStream = :id ORDER BY pubDate desc, updateDate desc");
      query.setParameter("id", rssStream.getId());
    }
    else
      query = session.createQuery("FROM RssFeed ORDER BY pubDate desc, updateDate desc");
    return query.list();
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public RssFeed get(String title) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (RssFeed) session.get(RssFeed.class, title);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public RssFeed save(RssFeed rssFeed) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(rssFeed);
    return rssFeed;
  }
}
```

Все обращения к БД идут через такие интерфейсы.

Соответственно вопрос, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: По описанию проблемы, ваши воркеры не понимают, что в БД может писать кто-то ещё. Нужно корректно формировать транзакции, блокировки страниц/строк/таблиц, и обрабатывать на воркерах ошибки совместного доступа.

Comment: @Vesper Я добавил один из сервисов для работы с БД. Ммм, а как решать такие проблемы? Я могу перехватить `Exception` в воркере, но разве сам драйвер или `datasource` не могут это взять на себя? И если висит блокировка, то дождаться, когда БД отпустят?

Comment: ЕМНИП от драйвера зависит, умеет он обрабатывать блокировки или нет. Думаю, правильнее считать, что нет.

Comment: @Vesper Так, а есть такой драйвер для `sqlite` на java? И `org.sqlite.JDBC` не у что не умеет корректно работать с блокировками?!

Comment: [Нет, и не умеет, а точнее, так и работает, потому что не thread safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707434/sqlite-in-a-multithreaded-java-application). Печально, но придется это обходить ручками.

Comment: Руками локи раставлять?

Comment: Вообщем помогло еще одно решение. [Тут][1] можно прочитать.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117248/spring-sqlite-in-multi-threaded-application

Comment: хм, то есть, вы поменяли db engine? Ну да, так работать должно, если новый движок умеет работать с потоками.

Comment: @Vesper, я еще не до конца разобрался в тонкостях `Java`, `Spring` и `Hibernate`, но я понял одно, эта штука позволяет хорошо контролировать сколько потоков одновременно стучаться базу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это штатный режим работы для sqlite, так как он представляет из себя только базу данных, а не сервер, который бы умел управлять многими соединениями и блокировкой записи. Поэтому правильно переписать все воркеры, чтобы работали через всего одно соединение с БД. Второй вариант - один поток общается с БД, заменяя собой локальный SQLite сервер, остальные передают ему запросы к БД.

Источник тут [SQLite in multithreaded Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707434/sqlite-in-a-multithreaded-java-application).

Comment: А если просто поставить `lock` в методе сохранения, легче будет?

Comment: Не видя кода, подсказать не смогу. Но по идее, не будет, так как JDBC опять кинет эксепшн, и его придется опять парсить, в итоге или костыли получатся, или аналог предложенного решения.

Comment: я же выложил код сервиса, который работает с БД. В других местах работа идёт через него.

Comment: Ну дык, в каждом потоке по current session, итого много потоков, гонки и конфликты при записи данных. Обходить надо, и это поведение у SQlite by design.